# using apt-cache search

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cache

I am learning how to use apt. When I do an `apt-cache search git`
to see all packages matching git, I see a bunch of packages whose
descriptions have nothing to do with git. Why is this so and
how can I fix it? (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS).

Also, why is the search functionality found in a command
that has "cache" in its name? What does search functionality
have to do with caches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

If you want only to search by name, use the `--names-only` argument. For more information, read the `man apt-cache`, it would be useful.

Answer (score 7):

When you perform an `apt-cache search <package name>` command, you are performing a query against the information stored on your local machine for available packages. This is the cache from your "subscribed" repositories. That is, the command is performing a query against the repositories that you have set up in USC(Ubuntu Software Center) or  Synaptic.

According to the `apt-cache` man page, `/etc/apt/sources.list` is the location to fetch information from in the query. There are a couple of additional locations for other types of package information. See `man apt-cache` for more details.

Essentially, running `apt-cache search git` will return all instances of available packages containing the word sequence "git" in the package name, as well as in the package description.

For example, this means that any package that may contain the word sequence "git" in it, like the word "di**git**al", in its description will also be returned as a result. Please note the bold in the previous sentence.

If you are only interested in packages that are specifically concerned with git - the source control manager, you will need to restrict your query to using a regular expression in order to make the search results more restrictive.

For example:

`sudo apt-cache search ^git$`

will return results that explicitly contain only the phrase "git" in the package name.

For example:

```
sudo apt-cache search ^git$
git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
```

The command:
`sudo apt-cache search ^git`

will return results for packages which begin with the phrase "git":

For example:

```
sudo apt-cache search ^git
git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
git-core - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (obsolete)
git-doc - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (documentation)
git-man - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)
gitk - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (revision tree visualizer)
easygit - git for mere mortals
gforge-plugin-scmgit - Git plugin for FusionForge (transitional package)
git-all - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (all subpackages)
git-annex - manage files with git, without checking their contents into git
git-arch - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (arch interoperability)
...
```

That said, you will need to tune your queries of the package cache to be more specific to your interest. Hope this helps.

Comment: "`apt-cache search ^git$` will only return results that contain "git" in the package name". I don't understand this, because, for example `git-man` (from the second output you posted) also contains `git`. Can you explain what do the caret and the $ symbols mean? I know that the caret means "begins with", but then this contradicts with the second output you posted (output of `^git`), because it's returning `easygit` =).

Comment: Oooh. The `^` means packages **and descriptions** that start with `git`. Okay, the second output is understood. So what does `^git$` return? Packages that start with `git` and ...?

Comment: @Alaa Think of the characters "^" and "$" as anchors to your query. `apt-cache search ^git$` will return, specifically, the git package. `apt-cache search ^git` will return packages that begin with the phrase "git" and will be less specific.

Comment: One could get a more generalized search result by running the query apt-cache search ^git?`

Comment: In order to have a more colorful output, one could enhance your command with `apt-cache search ^git | grep --color git`

Comment: Funny thing, it seems to find all combinations as well: I am looking for naps and it matches all the strings containing snap (e.g. vlcsnapshot), synapse,  userspace software suspend (userspace software suspend) etc. The `^git$` way suggested seems very handy but it is too narrow as it would exclude, say, "git2" (I know it doesn't exist, but just as an example).

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect answer to your question but still related to it since it's about package management. I personally use aptitude instead of apt-get. aptitude is the [synaptic](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) equivalent to terminal.

To search,

```
sudo aptitude search $keyword
```

Other commands

```
sudo aptitude install
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

To install aptitude,

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Comment: Keep in mind that aptitude may still be problematic on multiarch systems - so it's ok to use it for queries/searches but not so for installing/removing packages.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch explains how aptitude can be used for multiarch concerns

Comment: That page only mentions `aptitude why` - like I said "use it for queries" - the page is rather old too (edited 2012-02-08) - so my warning still stands.

Comment: I see. I'm an aptitude user so can you point me to an article where it says its a problematic on multiarch system? I may need to switch back to apt-get then.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768, it seems to have been fixed recently. I am still wary. Debian recommends apt-get too (docs for wheezy)

Comment: i see. well then, i'll continue using aptitude. im using a 64 bit Ubuntu btw.

Answer (score 0):

Install apt-xapian-index and use axi-cache search when searching instead of apt--cache. You'll get much better results