# Unable to install mailutils

Tags: command-line, apt, mailutils

I'm trying to install `mailutils` in Ubuntu. I'm getting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mailtuils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mailtuils
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using apt-cache search](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298506/using-apt-cache-search)

Comment: I don't see the logic of the duplicate suggestion at all. The problem looks like a typo so far.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear even if there wasn't a typo. The package you searched for simply does not exist in the repositories you have configured. That should be your first clue that you searched to the wrong package.

Comment: you have a type should be `mailutils` instead of `mailtuils `

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a typo in your command `mailtuils` instead of `mailutils` :

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Answer (score 5):

While it's clear that you have misspelled [the package name](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mailutils&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) simply correcting that doesn't guarantee success as you will get the same result if you don't have the correct repository enabled for that package. You'll note if you check the link above that Ubuntu Package Search indicates specific repositories in [**bold**] when and where required (as in this case)

Do the following:

**1)** Insure that the [Universe Repository is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

**2)** Use the correct package name in your command. `sudo apt-get install mailutils`

Answer (score 2):

Use `apt policy` to see what's wrong :

```
$ apt policy mailtuils
N: Unable to locate package mailtuils
```

Aha ... now what do I see ? ... a typo ! :D

```
$ apt policy mailutils
mailutils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.99.99-1.1ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1:2.99.99-1.1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
```

Double check `universe` is in your repositories:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
```

And here we go ...

```
$ sudo apt-get install mailutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils4 libntlm0 mailutils-common
Suggested packages:
  mailutils-mh mailutils-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils4 libntlm0 mailutils
  mailutils-common
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,285 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,657 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: I take it your Universe Repository is enabled mate! ;-)

Comment: Awww @ElderGeek you are probably most right. I'll revise my answer :)

Comment: @fkraiem You were right about the other answer. Thanks.